# httpd.exe application error

Tags: apache

when trying to install Apache service through Wamp Server, the following error comes up:

httpd.exe - Application error
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close application.

Port 80 is not actually being used.

I am running it in a Windows 7 machine. I have tried uninstalling it, removing the folder and registry keys but error persist.

Any help will be really appreciated it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the wampserver (32 bits and php 5.3) 2.2E  even if you have 64 bits windows 7.
I had the same problem. tried everything. But in the end this worked.  I have 64 bits windows 7 installed.