# WampServer Apache httpd.exe application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142) after Windows 10 Creators Update (1703))

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

The Windows 10 Creators update seems to have hosed Apache's httpd service, which now errors when I first start the WampServer.

The official form [confirms](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,146443) this suspicion.

WampServer version 3.0.6.

However, none of the suggested solutions on the forum worked, as of the time of this post. Thus, I've opened this question so that us community members can work to find a solution here.

Note that downgrading Windows is not a viable solution here.

Comment: Note that will the service appears to start after clicking OK on the error message, there is functionality impacted by the issue - one example is ability to use commands such as exec() and popen().

Comment: Just FYI - a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522171/httpd-exe-application-error has been closed as off topic

Comment: OMG, how I hate the draconian Microsoft!  I come back and my machine is rebooted, to this type of error... no files saved, updates to the system *I* didn't approve.  Time to go back to Ubuntu...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Update: looks like the 3.0.8 patch resolves the issues with WampServer 3.0.6 and the Windows 10 Creators Update.

It's not well publicized on the website, (you need to click the SourceForge link on the website and navigate the folder structure to find it.) Direct link to the update here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.0.9.exe/download

Update: looks like 3.0.8 has been pulled as 3.0.9 just came out; here's the link to 3.0.9:
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wampserver/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.0.9.exe?r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fwampserver%2Ffiles%2FWampServer%25203%2FWampServer%25203.0.0%2FUpdates%2F&ts=1498418727&use_mirror=pilotfiber

Comment: Worked for me too.  FYI, if you are installing, choose the same directory (mine was `C:\\wamp64`, not `C:\\wamp`, the default).

Comment: The link has been fixed to point at 3.0.9 update that replaces 3.0.8.